# Is there a way to output the backslash symbol in cout from a string?

Tags: c++, c++17

C++ code

```
fs::path pathToShow("C:\Windows\system.ini");
cout << "exists() = " << fs::exists(pathToShow) << "\n"
    << "root_name() = " << pathToShow.root_name() << "\n"
    << "root_path() = " << pathToShow.root_path() << "\n"
    << "relative_path() = " << pathToShow.relative_path() << "\n"
    << "parent_path() = " << pathToShow.parent_path() << "\n"
    << "filename() = " << pathToShow.filename() << "\n"
    << "stem() = " << pathToShow.stem() << "\n"
    << "extension() = " << pathToShow.extension() << "\n";
```

Taken from an example from [https://www.codingame.com](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5659/c17-filesystem)

Output

```
exists() = 0
root_name() = "C:"
root_path() = "C:"
relative_path() = "Windowssystem.ini"
parent_path() = "C:"
filename() = "Windowssystem.ini"
stem() = "Windowssystem"
extension() = ".ini"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Does Visual Studio have an compiler/linker option to threat the '\' symbol as

```
\\
```

when outputing with cout or printf? Or is there another simple way without making an own function to manipulate the string (without too much hazzle)?

Comment: Line 1 should be `fs::path pathToShow("C:\\Windows\\system.ini");`

Comment: Your string literal shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Thats weird. It does compile. But yeah, it worked after adding backslashes to the path. Thanks

Comment: With Clang, I get `error: unknown escape sequence '\W'`, `error: unknown escape sequence '\s'`.

Answer (score 4):

Not a compiler option, but a language feature: use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Should work on all compilers.

```
fs::path pathToShow(R"(C:\Windows\system.ini)");
```